# Alternate ways to acquire Divine Grace for a Chaotic character

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, multi-classing, archetype

I have a halfling bard with a silly-high CHA. Multi-classing for two levels of Paladin to get Divine Grace would be a superb mechanical fit for this character. But he is Chaotic in alignment beyond belief.

Are there any other classes/archetypes/feats to get a CHA bonus to all saving throws?

Comment: There are also variant rules for paladins from different alignments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to look at the Charisma section of [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o91Z-s0R7Vf2Ujj1lFqGC5W--9JOyU0I6uC9XRIR5to/edit#), but to summarize:

> - Unholy Resilience (AntiPaladin 2) Charisma to saves
> - Sidestep Secret (oracle, lore mystery, revelation) Use Charisma to Ac and reflex saves instead of dex
> - Prophetic Armor (Oracle 7, Lunar Revelation) Use Cha instead of dex for AC and reflex saves.
> - Friends to animals (oracle, nature mystery) Animals within 30 feet gain your Charisma to all saves
> - Final revelation (Oracle 20, Enlightened Philosopher ACF) add charisma to all saves in addition to dex,constitution and wis
> - Final Revelation (Oracle 20, Ancestor Mystery) Add CHA to Will saves
> - Undead: use charisma for HP, fort saves, and constitution based special ability
> - *Bestow Grace of the Champion* (charisma to saves, smite evil once)

So, probably you want a one-level Oracle dip for 'Friend to the Animals' with some method of getting yourself to count as an animal (e.g. *Instant Enemy* accessed via UMD and a *Page of Spell Knowledge*).  A couple levels in Antipaladin could also work, depending on your character, though. *Bestow Grace of the Champion* would be the best if you were Lawful Good, but it doesn't work on you.

The document also lists 'Divine Protection', which did exactly what you want, but it's been errata-nerfed into oblivion.

Comment: As an alternative, OP can go for a 2 level dip into Swashbuckler to give him access to [Charmed Life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/#TOC-Charmed-Life-Ex-). It's like Divine Protection, except he gets 3 uses instead of 1.

Comment: How does Instant Enemy helps him be treated as an animal for the purpose of Friend to the Animals? *"With this spell you designate the target as your favored enemy for the remainder of its duration. Select one of your favored enemy types. For the duration of the spell, you treat the target as if it were that type of favored enemy for all purposes."*

Comment: @ShadowKras It's an example.  For that example, you'd want favored enemy(animal), from e.g. the Object of Legend feat or an Enmity Fetish or someone in the party could have hunter's bond (companions) or the resonant power result number 10.  I'm not sure that's worth mentioning since there are so many different and relatively cheap ways to do it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but i really see no way for a humanoid character to count as an animal. I don't think something like that exists.

Comment: @ShadowKras http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96681/what-can-i-do-to-gain-the-animal-type Should be a self-answer but it's 2 am in my time zone so maybe tomorrow then :P

Answer (score 4):

**These feats are the closest as you get:**

- [Divine protection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/divine-protection/)
- [Steadfast personality](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/steadfast-personality/)

**and then there is a trait:**

- [Irrepressible](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/faith-traits/irrepressible/)

Divine protection used to do exactly what you wanted with this question, but it was nerfed to the state it is now.

Answer (score 2):

[thedarkwanderer’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96630/4563) seems to me to be a pretty good list of options for this, as-written.

But I think you should seriously consider deviating from things as they’re written here. Alignment is a deeply problematic part of the game for a variety of reasons, and I have long advocated for just ignoring it as much as possible. I think it is very bad for the game that divine grace is the unique province of lawful-good characters: it diminishes the diversity of the game.

Certainly, there is no *mechanical balance* need for strict alignment requirements. There is a slight corner case here (a CG paladin could take Desna’s Divine Fighting Technique to get both divine grace and the ability to use Cha for attack and damage with starknives—but then note that this clashes with how smite evil works and is actually not as good as it first seems, plus if you aren’t playing in Golarion, that DFT might very well be associated with an LG deity anyway), but that’s literally the worst of it. Otherwise, it’s trivial to just allow paladins of every alignment, with smite evil changing as necessary for the chosen alignment. (For that matter, even with the improvements to smite evil in Pathfinder, it would still be perfectly safe to allow paladins to just smite any foe—after all, plenty of paladins play in campaigns in which all their enemies *are* evil, and that doesn’t make them overpowered.)

So I would try asking your GM about doing a CG paladin, and it’s my personal (strongly-held) opinion that your game would be better if he or she allowed you to. You have a character in mind that you want to play who *is best represented in the game’s mechanics* using the paladin’s class feature. I do not think there is any good reason that a GM should prevent you from doing that.

Comment: I play in an online community that plays pretty strict RAW. I appreciate the sentiment, but I don't think it would fly.